# grep ignore if the word searched begin/end with a specific character

Tags: shell, grep

Here is my problem : I use `grep` to find a string into multiple files.

Let's say I am looking for the word "balloon". grep is returning lines containing balloon like "Here is a balloon", "loginxxballoonx", "balloon123" etc. This is not a problem except for one case : I want to ignore the line if it finds "/balloon/".

How can I look for every "balloon" strings in multiple files, but ignore those with / before and after (ignore "/balloon/")

EDIT : I will precise my problem a bit more : my strings to search for are stored in a file. I use `grep -f mytokenfile` to search for every strings stored in my "mytokenfile" file. For example, my file "mytokenfile" looks like this :

```
balloon
avion
car
bus
```

I would like to get all the lines containing these strings, with or without prefixes/suffixes, except if the prefix and suffix are "/".

Comment: As @RomanPerekhrest pointed out, you'll need a second grep call with invert-match. For example: grep -f mytokenfile testfile | grep -v -F "$(for token in $(cat mytokenfile); do echo /$token/; done)"

Answer (score 1):

Should work by using the negation sign ^

```
grep [^/]balloon[^/] ballonfile
```

Edit:
But this doesn't work if there is a 'balloon' not prefixed or suffixed by any other characters.

Comment: this will also capture such line as `"loginxxballoonx", "/balloon/"`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach(considering that there could be a line with multiple occurrences of search keyword such as `loginxxballoonx, sme text /balloon/ text`):

```
cat testfile | grep '[^/]balloon[^/]' | grep -v '/balloon/'
```

---

> **-v (--invert-match)**
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is
> specified by POSIX.)